# Dynamics Fetch XML Entity does not provide access to all attributes, GUID to String Cast Bug

Tags: c#, xml, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I get the following Exception when I wrap my code snippet in a try catch. And this calls out the bug that fixed my issue with the following code

Needed to change how I cast my GUID to string

```
spurgoUserData.Add("azureactivedirectoryobjectid", systemUser["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"].ToString()); // do NOT cast GUID using (string)
```

Logs

```
spurgoUserData.Add("azureactivedirectoryobjectid", systemUser["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"].ToString()); // do NOT cast GUID using (string)

fetch system user data with idea02a959-0895-469f-ac88-bacbe0b96d11
system user entity result Dynamics.SpurGo.Gamification.DataModel.SystemUser
DONE fetch user data
getting data systemUser['spurgo_name'] = Greg Degruy
Exception System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
at Dynamics.SpurGo.Gamification.DataAccess.DynamicsDataAccess.GetSpurGoUserData()
```

Below I am working with the [systemuser EntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/systemuser?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9).

My fetch XML is grabbing system user information in my org, I key attribute I want to grab from the Entity response in this fetch is the **azureactivedirectoryobjectidGuid** attribute which is a **Read Only**
**Edm.Guid**. It's going to be used in a bridge I am building to the Microsoft Graph API. When I query the Entity response from this fetch I seem to have not access to this attribute.

```
string xml = "<fetch distinct='false' version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' no-lock='true'>" +
                  "<entity name='systemuser'>" +
                      "<attribute name='azureactivedirectoryobjectid' />" +
                      "<attribute name='systemuserid' />" +
                      "<attribute name='fullname' />" +
                      "<attribute name='internalemailaddress' />" +
                      "<filter type='and'>" +
                          "<condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='eq' value='{" + userId.ToString() + "}' />" +
                           "<condition attribute='azureactivedirectoryobjectid' operator='not - null' />" +
                           "<condition attribute='internalemailaddress' operator='not-null' />" +
                           "<condition attribute='fullname' operator='not-null' />" +
                      "</filter>" +
                   "</entity>" +
              "</fetch>";
```

The resulting fetch response as tested in the Fetch XML Tester using the XrmToolBox gives me the following.

```
<result>
    <azureactivedirectoryobjectid>{2F3EAA47-FE7F-450F-97DE-00A03BA0F9C5}</azureactivedirectoryobjectid>
    <systemuserid>{EA02A959-0895-469F-AC88-BACBE0B96D11}</systemuserid>
    <fullname>Greg Degruy</fullname>
    <internalemailaddress>grdegr@grdegr.onmicrosoft.com</internalemailaddress>
</result>
```

But in my C# plugin, I use the logic below and can not seem to access this attribute as seen in the trace logs logs. It even shows crmonln instead of grdegr as my alias.

Plugin trace logs

```
DONE fetch user data
user data for spurgo_name is Greg Degruy
user data for internalemailaddress is crmoln@microsoft.com
```

Code snippet from Plugin

```
tracingService.Trace("fetch spurgo user data");
Entity spurGoUser = RetrieveSpurGoUser(organizationService, executionContext.UserId);
tracingService.Trace("fetch system user data");
Entity systemUser = RetrieveSystemUser(organizationService, executionContext.UserId);
tracingService.Trace("DONE fetch user data");

if (spurGoUser != null && systemUser != null)
{
    spurgoUserData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    spurgoUserData.Add("spurgo_name", (string)spurGoUser["spurgo_name"]);
    tracingService.Trace("user data spurgo_name " + spurgoUserData["spurgo_name"]);
    spurgoUserData.Add("internalemailaddress", (string)systemUser["internalemailaddress"]);
    tracingService.Trace("user data internalemailaddress " + systemUser["internalemailaddress"]);
            
    spurgoUserData.Add("azureactivedirectoryobjectid", systemUser["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"].ToString());
    tracingService.Trace("user data azureactivedirectoryobjectid " + spurgoUserData["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"]);
    spurgoUserData.Add("fullname", (string)systemUser["fullname"]);
    tracingService.Trace("user data " + spurgoUserData["fullname"]);

    return spurgoUserData;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are taking name from spurgoUserData but internalemailaddress from systemUser.. so you are saying RetrieveSystemUser method using the above same fetchxml query but not giving you the same result like xrmtoolbox? Did you apply the filter systemuserid with context user id ?

Comment: that's correct, in fact I get no result from my trace logs, i did and still no response. updated the post to include this fetch

Comment: Do you have try catch block, any exceptions written to trace?

Comment: great point, I do not. going to implement and see if I can capture the exception.

Comment: thanks for your feedback on this, Dynamics plugin trace logs and try catch has me debugging A LOT faster. making so much progress on this project now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cast a GUID from fetch XML you must use the following [ToString()](http://following%20ToString()) method.

```
spurgoUserData.Add("azureactivedirectoryobjectid", systemUser["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"].ToString());
```

Using an [explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) cast will not work, like this.

```
spurgoUserData.Add("azureactivedirectoryobjectid", (string)systemUser["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"]);
```